# update a the value in the table using php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update my table in the database using php but it did not update. I don't know where is the problem

**emember.php**

```
<?php

$id= $_GET['id'];
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","members");
$result=mysqli_query($con,"select * from member_info");

echo "<form action='update.php' method='post'>";
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<table border=1>";

//echo "Profile Id: <input type='text' name='profile_id' value = '$row[profile_id]'>    <br>"
echo "<tr>";
echo "<br>"."<tr>"."ID: <input type='text' name='id' value = '$row[id]'"."</tr>";
echo "<br>"."<tr>"."Username: <input type='text' name='username' value = '$row[username]'"."</tr>";
echo "<br>"."Password: <input type='text' name='password' value = '$row[password]'"."<br>";
 echo "<br>"."Firstname: <input type='text' name='firstname' value = '$row[firstname]'"."<br>";
echo "<br>"."Lastname: <input type='text' name='lastname' value = '$row[lastname]'"."<br>";
echo "<br>"."Address: <input type='text' name='address' value = '$row[address]'"."<br>";
echo "<br>"."Gender: <input type='text' name='gender' value = '$row[gender]'"."<br>";
echo "<br>"."Birthdate: <input type='text' name='birthdate' value ='.$row[birthdate]'"."<br>";


}
echo"</tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "<input type='submit' value = 'Save'>";
echo "</form>";

?>
```

the **update.php**

```
<?php
$id=$_POST['id'];
$username= $_POST['username'];
$password= $_POST['password'];
$firstname= $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname= $_POST['lastname'];
$address= $_POST['address'];
$gender= $_POST['gender'];
$birthdate= $_POST['birthdate'];

$con= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","members");
mysqli_query($con,"update member_info set     id='$id',username='$username',password='$password',firstname='$firstname',lastname='$lastname',address='$address',gender='$gender',birthdate='$birthdate' where id='$id'");

echo "Successfully updated!";
echo "Back to <a href='index.php'>home</a>";
?>
```

anyone can help what's wrong with my code?

Comment: In your `emember.php` , Access like this `$row['id']` instead of `$row[id]`

Comment: Do you want to update the entire table or just one row?

Comment: first try to echo all the values you got by POST method.. because if any single value is null then whole query won't work many of the time.. so check all the values first..

Comment: Also, after the `mysqli_query` , write `echo mysqli_error($con);` and let us know if it shows you any error

Comment: It's hard to find out what's going wrong. You need to find out if the query is failing or not by adding this line just after mysqli_query() to your code like this:
echo mysqli_error();

Comment: Unescaped $_POST values being injected directly into a query?!? Using MySQLi, but not using prepared statements? password in plaintext? How many times does basic security advice have to be rammed home before some developers start listening?

Comment: @MarkBaker I made one using prepare, look at my answer and let me know if you see any mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
<?php

// Your vars:
$id = $_POST['id'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
$birthdate = $_POST['birthdate'];

// Use of object based MySQLi:
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","members");

// Prepare your query:
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE member_info SET username = ?,
   password = ?,
   firstname = ?, 
   lastname = ?, 
   address = ?,
   gender = ?,
   birthdate = ?
   WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param($username,
   $password,
   $firstname,
   $lastname,
   $address,
   $gender,
   $birthdate,
   $id);

// Execute your query:
$stmt->execute();

// And close it! You're done!
$stmt->close();

echo "Successfully updated!";
echo "Back to <a href='index.php'>home</a>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, if the column "id" is auto_incremented, you won't be able to update it

Answer (score 0):

The problems I see in your code :

**emember.php**

`<input`  tag is not closed

`$row[id]` should be accessed as :

```
echo "<br>"."<tr>"."ID: <input type='text' name='id' value = '".$row["id"]."' /></tr>";
```

**update.php**

I think you shouldn't update `id` since you are updating a record for that specific `id`.
It should be:

```
"update member_info set username='$username',password='$password',firstname='$firstname',lastname='$lastname',address='$address',gender='$gender',birthdate='$birthdate' where id='$id'"
```

Comment: @user2699948 ok..good.. If you think one of the answers solved your problem, you should accept the answer. This will help other visitors (to this question ) select solved solution. thx.